# Routing Through Linux Network Names Spaces?

Tags: linux, networking

On my Linux VM (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS) I would like route packets through two
network name spaces. I have created two network name spaces and connected them using veth pairs.

My network topology looks like this -

```
dpn1_1 --veth-- dpn1_gw1 [NAME SPACE1] dpn1_gw1_if --veth-- dpn2_gw1_if [NAME SPACE2] dpn2_gw1 --veth-- dpn2_1
```

With following IP assignment for veth pairs -

dpn1_1 -- dpn1_gw1 (192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.2), 
where dpn1_gw1 is in NAME SPACE1 (named name_dpn1_gw1)

dpn1_gw1_if -- dpn2_gw1_if (192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.2)
where dpn1_gw1_if in NAME SPACE1 and dpn2_gw1_if is in NAME SPACE2 (named name_dpn2_gw1)

dpn2_gw1 -- dpn2_1 (192.168.3.1 - 192.168.3.2) 
where dpn2_gw1 is in NAME SPACE2

dpn1_1 and dpn2_1 are in the default name space

Objective :

I would like to ping dpn2_1 (192.168.3.2) from dpn1_1 (192.168.0.1) through
the dpn1_1 interface in the default name space.

This is what I did  :

Enabled IP forwarding in default name space, NAME SPACE1 and NAME SPACE2

```
/home/ganesh/testnets# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
/home/ganesh/testnets# ip netns exec name_dpn1_gw1 sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
/home/ganesh/testnets# ip netns exec name_dpn2_gw1 sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Added host routes in default name space, NAME SPACE1 and NAME SPACE2 to 
reach dpn2_1 via dpn1_1 and dpn1_1 via dpn2_1

Routing table in default name space

```
/home/ganesh/testnets# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth10
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth10
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth11
169.254.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth12
169.254.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth11
192.168.0.1     192.168.3.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn2_1
192.168.3.2     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn1_1
```

Routing table in NAME SPACE1

```
/home/ganesh/testnets# ip netns exec name_dpn1_gw1 route -n 
1
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 dpn1_gw1
192.168.0.1     192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn1_gw1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 dpn1_gw1_if
192.168.3.2     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn1_gw1_if
```

Routing table in NAME SPACE2

```
/home/ganesh/testnets# ip netns exec name_dpn2_gw1 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.1     192.168.1.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn2_gw1_if
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 dpn2_gw1_if
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 dpn2_gw1
192.168.3.2     192.168.3.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 dpn2_gw1
```

This did not work. When I

```
ping -I dpn1_1 192.168.3.2
```

ARP goes out for 192.168.3.2 on dpn1_1 (seen using wireshark) even though I have a static host route configured. 
Why is this ?

I tried to work around this issue by enabling proxy ARP on both name spaces.
This resulted in ICMP packet reaching NAME SPACE1 but again ARP broadcast goes
out for 192.168.3.2 on dpn1_gw1_if from NAME SPACE1 to NAME SPACE2 which NAME
SPACE2 did not reply, so ping failed.

Any suggestions ?